# Was bedeutet "ausmachen"?

Tags: meaning

Ich hab diesen Satz gelesen:

> Wasser macht davon etwa die Hälfte aus.

Was bedeutet das Verb *ausmachen*?

Ich glaube, dass die Bedeutung von diesem Wort auf Englisch (amount to) ist. Stimmt das?

Comment: Was sagt das Wörterbuch?

Comment: ich suche im internet nach (ausmachen) , und finde viele bedeutungen , deswegen ich frage hier diese frage

Comment: https://www.dwds.de/wb/ausmachen - welche Bedeutung passt hier, besonders im Hinblick auf die Beispielsätze? Wenn es um Bedeutungen geht, ist Das Digitale Wörterbuch der Deutschen Sprache (dwds.de) Dein bester Freund.

Comment: *Fragen fragen* klingt nicht so gut wie *Fragen stellen*.

Comment: Ich glaube , dass die Bedeutung von diesem Wort auf Englisch (amount to) ist

Comment: Ich bedanke mich übrigens bei ihnen sehr für dies Wörterbuch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In diesem Falle bedeutet ausmachen etwas wie **bestehen aus**. Dein Beispiel besagt, dass die Hälfte (50%) des Dativobjektes **aus** Wasser **besteht**.

Comment: Willkommen beim Stackexchange der deutschen Sprache. Bitte wundere dich nicht, wenn deine Antwort wenig Wertschätzung erfahren wird; in ihrer jetzigen Form ist die Frage schließwürdig und wird daher wahrscheinlich wenig beachtet. Du kannst jedoch gerne auch andere Fragen beantworten.